# How to find where Cache-Control is set on "private, no-store"?

Tags: http, deployment, typo3

My site is not caching, I think. I've been told that's why my site has a low performance on loading.

```
~/# curl -I http://my.site/                      ✔ 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 21:06:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 89044
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Language: de
Cache-Control: private, no-store
```

After I disabled a plugin on my CMS backend the cache max-age starts working again:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86314
```

How can I solve this issue? I'm not too knowledgeable on this. Does that mean that this plugin is making some kind of request without caching?

Any tip on how can approach to start finding where is the problem?

Comment: If the page is cached after you deactivate a plugin, the plugin is maybe set to non-cachable (as a USER_INT in TYPO3 terms). So, investigate the configuration of this specific plugin and why it is set to uncached - this may have a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Performance optimization in TYPO3 is a very broad topic with a lot of places where you can start with optimization. Without knowing your TYPO3 version and which plugin you disabled, it's hard to tell what went wrong.

You should invest some time to research on the different topics.

In general I would advise to read the docs section about [caching in TYPO3](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Index.html).

The extension [StaticFileCache](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/staticfilecache/) can help you in two ways:

1. It caches completely rendered TYPO3 pages in your filesystem. However setup of this extension isn't that easy because configuring the .htaccess rules might be tricky.
2. But even if you don't set up the static file cache the extension also delivers a backend module which can tell you, if there are caching issues in your site.